# What is the equivalent of CssNode in the newer versions of AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I have a block of code like this that works in AngleSharp 0.9.3:

```
public IEnumerable<CssNode> FindNodesInStyle(StyleContext context)
{
    if (context is InternalStyleContext)
    {
        var nodes = new HashSet<CssNode>();

        var styleSheet = context.ProcessedStyleSheet;
        var rules = this.GetRules(styleSheet);
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            var node = styleSheet.ParseTree.GetAssociatedNode(rule);
            if (node != null && !nodes.Contains(node))
            {
                nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }
    else
    {
        return new CssNode[] { };
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update my AngleSharp to the latest version - currently, 0.12.1 - and CssNode has been removed.  I have imported [AngleSharp.Css](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Css) but that also does not contain a CssNode class.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is unfortunately much more complicated than that (i.e., AngleSharp pre v0.10). If you look for a type that can be used for almost anything CSS the closest would be `IStyleFormattable`. Otherwise, if you only look for rules then `ICssRule` would be for you.

Not sure what you want to do with your code - AngleSharp.Css has already helpers to, e.g., get you all rules (with descendants etc. - also following media rules and similar only if they apply).

If you give out more details what exactly you try to achieve I'll update the answer accordingly.

Hope that helps!